# Cyclicity of Aut ($ Z_n $)

Tags: group-theory

Let Aut($G$) denote group of automorphisms of group $G$. Which of following is not a cyclic group?

1. Aut$ (Z_4) $
2. Aut$(Z_6) $
3. Aut $(Z_8) $
4. Aut $(Z_{10}) $

I know that in general Aut $(Z_n) $ is isomorphic to $ U_n $. So here when $U_n $ is cyclic then Aut $ (Z_n) $ will be cyclic.
But how to decide for what valus of n $ U_n $ is cyclic? Is there way to decide without looking into elements of $ U_n $ to say for what values of n $ U_n $ is cyclic?

Comment: The groups involved are so small that you should just *check* them directly. That is why your (homework?) problem does not have something like $U_{121}$ in it. (There are general theorems about when $U_n$ is cyclic, but it's good practice to work with the elements of the small groups to see if any are cyclic so you get some computational practice.)

Comment: This wasn't my homework problem but a question from a exam in previous year. Can u refer that theorm when U (n) in cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am getting

$U_4=\{1,3\}\rightarrow 3$ an element of order 2

$U_6=\{1,5\}\rightarrow 5$ an element of order 2

$U_8=\{1,3,5,7\}\rightarrow 3^2=5^2=7^2=1$ no  element of order 4

and $U_{10}=\{1,3,5,7\}\rightarrow 3$  an element of order 4

so 3  is not cyclic.Please check

Comment: In $U_8$ element $3$ has order 2. In fact, every nontrivial element has order 2, hence it is Klein four-group.

Comment: right you are @lisyarus

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $U(n)$ is cyclic iff $n$ is 1, 2, 4, $p^k$ or 2$p^k$ (where p is an odd prime). See [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/269059834797.pdf) for proof.